# Please could someone check my answers to these basic group theory exercise

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> So I've tried to solve this exercise and I was wondering if someone
>   would check my answer and tell me if it is correct please?

Exercise:

Part 1: Suppose $a$ is a group element such that $a^6 = e$. What are possibilities for $|a|$?

Part 2: Let $x$ be an element of a group such that $x^2 \neq e$ and $x^6 = e$. Show that $x^4 \neq e$ and $x^5 \neq e$. What can we say about the order of $x$?

My answer:

Here $e$ denotes the neutral element and $|x|$ denotes the order of the element $x$.

Part 1: I think we can only say that $|a| \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Part 2: First the claim $x^4 \neq e$. I prove it by contraditction:

Assume $x^4 = e$. Then $x^{-1} = x^3$ hence $x$ and $x^3$ have the same order. But $(x^3)^2 = e$ so $x^3$ has order $2$ which implies $x$ has order $2$ which contradicts $x^2 \neq e$ hence we must have $x^4 \neq e$.

For the claim $x^5 \neq e$ I also assumed $x^5 = e$. Then $x^6 = x$ which contradicts $x^2 \neq e$ since it would imply $x=e$.

Comment: For part 1, indeed $|a|\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ however some of those are impossible for $|a|$.  If $|a|=5$ could $a^6=e$?  Are there others which it couldn't be?  For part 2, it follows immediately from the correct answer to part 1.

Comment: Part 2 is okay. Part 1 you can tell a lot, lot, lot more about |a| than just that.

Comment: In fact in part 2 you just showed that Part 1 can't have |a| = 4,5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1:  |a| could be 1 ($a = e$ and $a^6 = e$); |a| could be 2 ($a^2 = e$ so $a^6=  (a^2)^3 = e$.) |a| could be 3. ($a^3 = a$ then $a^6 = (a^3)^2 = 3$). |a| can not be 4, or 5 (see part 2). |a| could be 6.  |a| can't be greater than 6 obviously.

Part 2:  $a^4 = e => a^8 = a^6a^2 = ea^2 = a^2 = e$ A contradiction.  $a^5 = e => e=a^6 = a^5 a = ea =a$ so a =e and $a^2 = e$.  A contradiction.

However we can cut to the chase and notice that if $a^m = e$ then $|a|$ divides m. (Let |a| = k, assume when we divide k into m we get v with l as a remainder (i.e. $l < k$.  Then $e =a^m = (a^k)^v a^l = e a^l = a^l$ so but $k = |a|$ is the smallest such power.  So $l= 0$ and $k|m$.

Part 1: becomes $|a| \in \{1,2,3,6\}$ because those are the divisors of 6.

Part 2: $|a| \ne 4$ because 4 does not divide 6. $|a| \ne 5$ for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1: Order of $a$ is a factor of $6$.

Part 2: It seems good. But we can say another way.

Assuming that $x^4 = e$. Then we have $e = x^6 = x^2.x^4 = x^2.e = x^2$. It contract with $x^2 \neq e$.